# How to make a testing branch the main branch that is pushed to git?

Tags: git, github

I have two branches, master and testing. Within testing I made some changes that conflicted with master. Now I can't merge them. But when I push to heroku and github, I push the master branch always. Is there any way to override this and make the testing branch the one that is used for pushing and such?

Thanks!

Comment: what is thye command that you used to push. is it only git push?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you merge the changes into master.  You just need to fix the conflicts:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge testing
$ edit file-with-conflict
$ git add file-with-conflict
$ git commit
```

Or, if you think that the files in your "master" branch are correct and you simply want to discard the conflicting changes in your master branch:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge -X theirs testing
```

To do what you're asking (push the testing branch to Heroku), you can do this:

```
$ git checkout testing
$ git push origin master
```

This will push your current branch to the "master" branch at a remote named "origin" (which I assume is what your heroki remote is called).  You can make this the default by adding "-u":

```
$ git push -u origin master
```